# HSQL DB lost when spring-boot app restarts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hsqldb, liquibase

I'm using liquibase to initialize my db in my springboot app and it works fine until I restart - the db is re-initialized wiping all the data.

Here are my application properties

```
# Liquibase
liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/iot-db.xml
liquibase.check-change-log-location=true

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=
entitymanager.packagesToScan=com.whatever
```

Are there properties which will allow me to create a persistent db instead of an in memory db?

Comment: what is your connection url?

Comment: Well, most likely you are working with an in-memory database. Please read http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql

Comment: That's my problem - it's configured as an in memory db and I need to initialize a persistent db if it doesn't exist or use it if it does. I'll mess around with the spring.datasource properties referred in the doc. Thanks

Comment: @Bacon Did you find an embedded/in-memory solution that persists across restarts? I'm trying to something similar with clustered caching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in `application.properties`, set this property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
```

[source and more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/819651)

Comment: Did not fix it for me (was 'none' before)