# Spring-boot H2 DB lost data if process is killed

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I've my spring-boot application working with H2 DB on the file.

The current H2 db string is:

> spring.datasource.url:
>   jdbc:h2:./myApp-@project.version@;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE

When I save my objects into the DB using the dao:

> @Transactional public interface MyDao extends
>   JpaRepository {
>   }
>
> myDao.save(new MyEntity(var1, var2);

and I stop my application with

> SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext, exitCode);

everything is ok, at the next restart the DB contains the saved objects.

The problem is when I start the application, I save something in the DB and the **java process is killed**. At the next restart the saved datas **are lost**.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you give more details about "I save something in the DB and the java process is killed" ?

Comment: I use my Dao to save the entity:
@Transactional
public interface MyDao extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

}

myDao.save(new MyEntity(var1, var2));

Comment: And who kill the java process ? You ? Can you post the log if it contains some information ?

Comment: I kill the java process (kill -9 processId), for test purpose OR the system shutdown unexpectedly. The log contains no informations after the kill

Comment: In this case, it has no relation with Spring Boot. You want to check the solidity of the recovery. In this case, you should use tools provided by H2 to check if the recovery works. Look at "Using the Recover Tool" in http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913643/hsql-db-lost-when-spring-boot-app-restarts try this sol.
not sure about u but it helped me